# Failed to load config from \Project\vuejs-frontend\vite.config.js: VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vite

My Project was running fine yesterday but after revisiting project today I came across this error when trying to run the project.

Here is my **vite.config.js** file:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
failed to load config from C:\Users\Desktop\Learn\Project\vuejs-frontend\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: The service was stopped
    at C:\Users\Desktop\Learn\Project\vuejs-frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1337:25
    at C:\Users\Desktop\Learn\Project\vuejs-frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:666:9
    at Socket.afterClose (C:\Users\Desktop\Learn\Project\vuejs-frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:644:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Please share with me any helpful tips you know. Thank you

Comment: I saw and used some projects that import `fileURLToPath` and `URL` but from `url`, not `node:url`.
Otherwise looks fine to me

Answer (score 11):

Please check your node version, in my case i update my node version {node: 'v14.17.6'} as showed bellow, and everything goes well.

--- Log ---
package: 'vite@3.0.2',
required: { node: '^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0' },
current: { node: 'v14.17.6', npm: '8.15.0' }

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks that helped! I had v15.12 and after switching to v16.10 it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I have take a similar error prompt but I am work with react, I just solved this typing the command:

```
$npm update
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a newer verison of node js, I am running 18.x and still want to use Vite, then adapt your code a little bit.

change the code that sets the export default

```
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      // https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#big-list-of-options
    }
  }
})
```

to be

```
  const defineConfig = ({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      // https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#big-list-of-options
    }
  }
});
export default defineConfig;
```

basically you are setting defineConfig to be a constant and then exporting that. It works fine on any version of node js

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to stem from fact that laravel uses vite 2 while current vite is 3 and yet seems jetstream just installs latest dependencies without considering such. Hence you have to manually try out versions that play well with each other. Currently what worked for me is:

```
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.2.1",
    "vite": "^2.9.11",
    "vue": "^3.2.31"
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
```

it seems the **laravel-vite-plugin** are **laravel-vite-plugin**  dependencies are the most conflicting.

*To make the changes you can edit the package.json and run npm install or npm install the specific packages specifying the version get installation the link from npm for correct format.*

This held me down for quite some hours. Thing is not even about node as above answer as myself was on 16.17, though check on that too, upgrading node ended up in up in more problems about openssl because i had postgres installed too which adds the config in path. I did not want to touch that. After fidgeting around creating separate project and installing breeze separately i caught the error.

I got a hint of whats going on from this [tweet](https://twitter.com/PovilasKorop/status/1548604689943494658?s=20&t=lsoaZbQiI78USbxe9xC1YA) from Povilas of Laravel daily after hours of scouring the internet.

Question is similar to mine if am not wrong:

[check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73979439/how-do-i-install-laravel-jetstream-with-the-official-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem, and it's because your Vite version doesn't match node version.

you need to update your node to the latest, it's very easy.

just download the latest version of node at https://nodejs.org/en/ and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error while setting up and working with vite, i solved it by importing `import { resolve } from 'path'`  in the my `vite.config.js` file as seen in the doc here https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest node version form [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en) solved the issue for me.
Check your version using command -

```
node -v
```

My old version was - v14.15.1

New version is - v18.17.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my fix was to remove `node_modules` folder and then re-run `npm install`

Answer (score -1):

I´m having the same problem but haven´t been able to solve the problem,
I thought the problem may have been mine node version but I have 16.17.0.

this is how my vite.config.js file looks:

```
     import { defineConfig } from "vite";
     import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

        export default defineConfig({
           plugins: [react()],
      });
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33575354)