# Error when starting dev server, Vite with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I closed the project to sleep, and in the other day, I've tried to "npm run dev", and this log came to me:

```
failed to load config from F:\Projetos\Atividades_e_Outros\PokedexReact\PokedexReact\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: The service was stopped
    at F:\Projetos\Atividades_e_Outros\PokedexReact\PokedexReact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1073:25
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (F:\Projetos\Atividades_e_Outros\PokedexReact\PokedexReact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:697:9)
    at Socket.afterClose (F:\Projetos\Atividades_e_Outros\PokedexReact\PokedexReact\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:687:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

My vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

I tried to run the terminal as admin and didn't worked too.
My node ver is 18.16.0 and my npm ver is 9.5.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load config from \Project\vuejs-frontend\vite.config.js: VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73023183/failed-to-load-config-from-project-vuejs-frontend-vite-config-js-vuejs)